# How to get the 'state' of an element in python-selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

In python-selenium there are two ways to find an element.

First, you can use the actual method to find an element, e.g.

```
element = find_element_by_xpath(myxpath)
```

Second, you can use the `WebDriverWait` to make sure the webdriver waits for some timeout until the element has been found *in some given state*:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, myxpath)))
```

For the latter method you can define several 'expected conditions' (see [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions)):

```
element_located_to_be_selected, element_to_be_clickable, element_to_be_selected etc.
```

---

My question: Using only the **first method** of finding an element, how can I check which state this element is in (in case I found the element). How can I check if is 'clickable', or 'selectable' etc.? Is there an attribute of the `element` object that I can use to determine the *state* of the element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, there is no direct method to retrieve the exact **state** of a WebElement through *Selenium*.

---

### find_element_by_xpath(xpath)

[find_element_by_xpath()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath) would simply find the first matching WebElement using the *xpath*. If no matching element is found it will raise [NoSuchElementException](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html#selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException)

But *Selenium* offers multiple methods to validate the state of a *WebElement* as follows:

- [**`is_displayed()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_displayed): Returns a Boolean value (true / false) whether the element is visible to a user or not.
- [**`is_enabled()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_enabled): Returns a Boolean value (true / false) whether the element is enabled or not.
- [**`is_selected()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_selected): Returns a Boolean value (true / false) whether the element is selected or not.

---

### WebDriverWait() in-conjunction with expected_conditions class

The canned [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) are generally useful to access the elements when they achieves a **definite state** as follows:

- [`presence_of_element_located(locator)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located) mentions :

  ```
  class selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(locator)

  An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible.
  ```
- [`visibility_of_element_located(locator)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located) mentions :

  ```
  class selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(locator)

  An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.
  ```
- [`element_to_be_clickable(locator)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) mentions:

  ```
  class selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable(locator)

  An Expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it.
  ```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any `is_clickable()` function or attribute. Looking at the [source code](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.html#element_to_be_clickable)

```
class element_to_be_clickable(object):
    """ An Expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that
    you can click it."""
    def __init__(self, locator):
        self.locator = locator

    def __call__(self, driver):
        element = visibility_of_element_located(self.locator)(driver)
        if element and element.is_enabled():
            return element
        else:
            return False
```

you can see `element_to_be_clickable` uses `visibility_of_element_located`, which waits for visibility using `element.is_displayed()`, and checks if the element is enabled using `element.is_enabled()`. You can check the combination of those two.

For `element_located_to_be_selected` you do have a function, `element.is_selected()`.

<sup>Regarding the "click()", it doesn't appear in the Python [WebElement API](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement), but in [Java's API](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#click--) it stats "There are some preconditions for an element to be clicked. The element must be visible and it must have a height and width greater then 0", checking those parameters should suffice.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('?')
href_data = button.get_attribute('href')
if href_data is None:
is_clickable = False
```

Comment: Not all clickable elements redirect, element can be clickable and perform action without `href` attribute.